# How to create an object/entity XOM-BOM using lists

Tags: ibm-odm

I need create object with an attribute that is based on a list of other objects. By default when creating a XOM using XSD, Rule Designer assigns lists as vector of java object. I need some orientation how to verbalize and instantiate the list and add the object members.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate Class of Objects you want to store in the list. After that you have to create a list type variable in your Request Class. "listOfMyObjects" as an example. Then, after updating your BOM instance, you will see a new member in it. You can verbolize it as you need. "{list of my objects} from {this}", where the "my object" itself have to be verbolized as well, as an example.

After that you can work with the list in your rules like that:

definition: make this object equals to any of My Object from list of my objects
if: your condition
then: add new object to list of my objects